# How to select from 3+ tables in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 database that holds more than 12 tables, I would like to select data from all of the tables, or at least four of the tables.

However, nothing seems to be working. I don't think that I can JOIN the tables in any way because the ID's are different.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT  
    table1.field,
    table2.field,
    table3.field

    FROM table1 

    LEFT JOIN table2 
        ON table1.id = table2.id
        LEFT JOIN table3
        ON table3.id = table1.id
 ")or die();
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are those tables related to each other? You can't just randomly join things together and expect to get sensible results.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $query = mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT  
    table1.field,
    table2.field,
    table3.field

    FROM table1 

    LEFT JOIN table2 
        ON 1 
        LEFT JOIN table3
        ON 1 
 ")or die();
```

`JOIN` is normally used if there is a relation between the tabes. That's the reason it needs an `ON` condition.

This will work, but you could also say:

```
"SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT field FROM TABLE1 
UNION 
SELECT field FROM TABLE2
UNION 
SELECT field FROM TABLE3
UNION 
...
) AS name
"
```

See here difference between between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp